# How to implement Drag and Drop using GWT with touch gesture

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

Need to implement drag and drop using `GWT` with gesture :

**Use case**: like if we drag a panel with touch only its shadow image (or some grey box) start to drag from there with original panel being at its original location and we should be able to drop that shadow(or pseudo box) at desired droppable pane and some pop up should come up.

Comment: See [GWT Drag and Drop Library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.allen-sauer.gwt.dnd/gwt-dnd)  by Allan Sauer (and [demo](https://gwt-dnd.appspot.com/) page). You can use drag proxy to have 'shadow only' drag effect.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not use any library for this.

Since browsers change, sometimes these libraries get broken. When you are using these libraries all that happens inside is some black magic and you will have a hard time to fix.

That is why I always implement DND myself. Also basic DND is really very easy to do and only a handfull lines of code. A library is overkill in a lot of situations.

Anyway. Over at G-Widgets a nice guide of how to do DND yourself is available:  http://www.g-widgets.com/2015/12/24/drag-and-drop-using-gwt/

Comment: For my requirement . Drag events are not helful , i need touch gesture to perform drag like event . Could you help with that. Code provided in above link with drag start event are not helful for touch event

Comment: As far as I know drag events are just like touch events. It will just work on mobile devices in my opinion. If you want advanced touch stuff look at hammer for GWT. For example https://github.com/geomajas/geomajas-project-hammer-gwt